# How to remove special chars like à®© from string in R using regex

Tags: r, regex, tweets

How do I remove the below chars from tweets in a R dataframe using regex

à®…à®©à¯à®ªà¯à®®à¯ à®ªà®¾à®šà®®à¯à®®à¯ à®¨à®¿à®±à¯ˆà®¨à¯à®¤ à®‡à®¸à¯à®²à®¾à®®à®¿à®¯ à®šà®•à¯‹à®¤à®° à®šà®•à¯‹à®¤à®°à®¿à®•à®³à¯ à®•à¯à®•à¯ à®°à®®à¯à®œà®¾à®©à¯ à®¨à®²à¯à®µà®¾à®´à¯à®¤à¯à®¤à¯à®•à¯à®•à®³à¯ â€¦

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: check for some encoding mistake in your code

Comment: This regex worked for me, I dont know how. (@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \\t])|(\\w+://\\S+)

Comment: iconv(yourstringhere, "UTF-8", "ASCII", sub = "")

Comment: try above code!

Comment: even this works!Thanks bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer goes out to Rushabh. You can use `iconv` which converts the strings with one encoding to another and substitutes nonconversable charaters with the value given in argement `sub`:

```
foo <- "à®…à®©à¯à®ªà¯à®®à¯ à®ªà®¾à®šà®®à¯à®®à¯ à®¨à®¿à®±à¯ˆà®¨à¯à®¤ à®‡à®¸à¯à®²à®¾à®®à®¿à®¯ à®šà®•à¯‹à®¤à®° à®šà®•à¯‹à®¤à®°à®¿à®•à®³à¯ à®•à¯à®•à¯ à®°à®®à¯à®œà®¾à®©à¯ à®¨à®²à¯à®µà®¾à®´à¯à®¤à¯à®¤à¯à®•à¯à®•à®³à¯ â€¦"
iconv(foo, from = "UTF-8", to = "ASCII", sub = "")
```

Output:

```
[1] "aaaaaaa aaasaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa asaaaa asaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa a"
```